# Multi-selector JQuery Handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

In the interest of not duplicating code, I was hoping there is a way to encapsulate both of these selectors into 1

The 2 selectors are as follows:

```
 //Radio Button Group
 $("#ContactMethod").on("change", function(e) {

    //SAME CODE
 });

 //Submit button
  $(".btn").on("click", function(e) {}

        //SAME CODE
  );
```

Comment: you can use the call the same function on both events

Comment: @tkay Yes he can, but he shouldn't.

Comment: @Satpal I disagree about the duplicate here. The event assigned to each elements are not the same. The duplicated answer doesn't work here, and the answer here is not the same as the duplicated one.

Comment: Yeah, they aren't the same question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them call the same function.

```
$("#ContactMethod").on("change", mySameCode);
$(".btn").on("click", mySameCode);

function mySameCode(){
   //some code
}
```